# How do I figure out my attic ventilation CFM - california fire safe vents

Tags: attic, ventilation

I'm looking to install a whole house fan for my 1700sqft house in northern CA. The install doesn't seem too complicated, but I don't know how to calculate the total amount of ventilation I have in my attic, with a combination of these vents:

- 3x shielded vents
- 9x frieze block vents

[image: shielded vents (high on the roof)]
[image: frieze block vents]

I'm having trouble finding numbers for either of these vents (roof was done before we bought the place) and I want to make sure I don't end up pushing too much air into the attic.

Comment: Just realized I have a cupola as well - it's in a fairly low part of the attic and over some HVAC ducting so I can't get to it, but it may be adding a lot of ventilation

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information instead of using comments.

Comment: If its a two story house, then please post teh area of the attic space.

Answer (score 1):

Basic calculation is based on air exchange's in the room.

For that, get the total volume of the attic by square feet multiplied with average height.

Once you have the volume divide it by 5 air exchanges per hour..

The higher the air exchange number the better.

For simplicity let's say you have 1000 sqft area by 4 ft height.

The volume is 4000 cubic feet. To get 5 air changes per hour multiply with 5. That is 4000*5 = 20,000 cf.

A 400 CFM fan will do 400*60 min = 24,000 cf per hour.

So you need 400 CFM fan and appropriate vents in and out.

To get vent sizes look up in the ducting tables.